# BackboneJS: How to cascade Model#destroy?

Tags: javascript, mysql, backbone.js

I have a relational DB (MySQL) at the backend and cool BackboneJS at the frontend. I have several tables (models in BackboneJS jargon) that are interconnected through foreign keys.

**PROBLEM**

How do I destroy a specific model, such that destruction cascades to all child models?

**EXAMPLE**

Consider this quick schema:

```
PERSON
id
name

PHONE_NUMBER
id
person_id
number

EMAIL_ADDRESS
id
person_id
email
```

Consider that we have a person "Jack" stored in DB with some phone numbers and email addresses. Also, we have BackboneJS models/collections defined for all of the 3 tables and data is loaded into them. A user on the frontend decides to delete records of Jack with a click.

Now here are a few approaches to delete all records of Jack:

**APPROACH#1**

Call "destroy" on all models of PhoneNumbers and EmailAddresses related to Jack, then call "destroy" on Jack itself.

**Problem(s)**

- Too many AJAX calls for one action.
- User will have to wait for a lot of time. (More dependants, more time)
- Deletion will be non-transactional. If user closes the browser during, data will be corrupted.

**APPROACH#2**

Define foreign key relationships at database level, that ensure cascade deletion of PHONE_NUMBERs and EMAIL_ADDRESSes when a PERSON row is deleted. Then "destroy" BackboneJS model for Jack at frontend.

- BackboneJS Models for dependants will never know what happened to their corresponding records in the backend. So they'll remain intact.

**APPROACH#3**

Create a URL on server side application "/thoroughly-delete-person" (which makes sure to delete a person with all of its dependants) and invoke it from the frontend instead of calling BackboneJS's Model#destroy on Jack.

- Same problem as in Approach#2

So seems like there is no perfect solution for this simple problem. Did you face it too? What approach did you take and why was it better?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, and I went with approach #2, except with one difference.

If you can, represent `Jack` as a single Backbone Model that contains `phone_number` and `email_address`. You can pass the `Jack` model to other Backbone Views to share `Jack`'s model data. You can then call `destroy` on the `Jack` model.

On the backend I used an `on delete cascade`, so I could just make a query:

`delete from PERSON where id = JACK_ID;`

I don't know the syntax for mysql but something like:

```
 PERSON
  id
  name

 PHONE_NUMBER
  id  references PERSON (id) on delete cascade
  person_id
  number

 EMAIL_ADDRESS
  id  references PERSON (id) on delete cascade
  person_id
  email
```

I'm not sure how well this will fit with your current problem context, but this is similar to what I did, and it works for me.

Comment: Thanks for response. For a `contains` relationship, this approach is fine. For related entities with separate BackboneJS models, question remains how to alert BackboneJS child models that their corresponding rows in database have been deleted.

Comment: @craftsman, if this isn't a `contains` (one-to-many) relationship, but instead a `related` (many-to-many) relationship, then the decision to delete related models is no longer a given (you could be deleting shared email addresses or phone numbers out from under another person) and would be custom logic, so you would probably go with #1 or #3 with client-side cache/collection invalidation. You can have separate models with a `contains` relationship, see https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/wiki/Extensions%2C-Plugins%2C-Resources#relations.